# 500 error when trying to create page using REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm currently using Confluence server and I'm currently getting a 500 error when I try to create a new page using the REST API. I am currently using an HTML macro that makes GET & POST requests using the Fetch API. I currently have no issues when making GET requests, only issues with POST requests.

I tried researching the error and saw someone mention that they fixed it by turning off collaborative editing in the space, but in my case that is not an option. Anyone have an idea of what is causing this error?

```
function createPage() { 
    let url = "http://exampledomain:8090/confluence/rest/api/content/"
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Basic USER:PASS',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            'type': 'page',
            'title': "New Page",
            'ancestors': [{ 'id': 97059352 }], // parent page id
            'space': { 'key': "EXAMPLE_SPACE" },
            'body': {
                'storage': {
                    'value': "<h1>New Page!</h1>",
                    'representation': 'storage',
                }
            },
        }
    })
     .then(response => console.log(response))
     .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
}
```

Comment: And would you post also the error message you're getting?

Comment: I also suggest to troubleshoot REST API calls via REST API Browser add-on installed into Conluence: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211542/atlassian-rest-api-browser?hosting=server&tab=overview.

Comment: @CraZ I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error, the message is empty in the error reponse

Answer (score 1):

I see invalid data structure:

```
                    'representation': 'storage',   <== extra comma
                }
            },                                     <== another extra comma
        }
```

Also double check with your programming language that you can use single quotes (`'`) and that they are correctly transformed into double quotes (`"`). JSON (Jira REST API) accepts only double quotes for keys and string values.